# Wrong output when doing double array in pow()

Tags: c, arrays, double, pow

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
FILE *infile, *outfile;
int main(){
    double landa, mu, lo, blocking_prob[4], mean_arrival_rate,
           mean_service_rate, k[4], p[4];

    infile = fopen("mm1.in", "r");
    outfile = fopen("mm1.out", "w");

    fscanf(infile, "%d %d %d %d %d %d",
        &mean_arrival_rate, &mean_service_rate,
        &k[0],&k[1],&k[2],&k[3] );

    lo = mean_arrival_rate / mean_service_rate;

    fprintf(outfile,
        "Initial setting : mean_arrival_rate = %d , mean_service_rate = %d \n\n",
        mean_arrival_rate,mean_service_rate);
    for(int x=0;x<4;x++) {
        printf("%f \n",pow(lo,k[x]) );
        blocking_prob[x]= ( (1-lo)*pow(lo,k[x]) ) / (1- pow(lo,k[x]+1));
        fprintf(outfile,"Blocking Probability is %f when K = %d \n\n",
            blocking_prob[x],k[x]);
    }
}
```

The output starts from **pow(lo,k[x])** , it outputs the wrong number.

I've tried to replace k[] with const (ex. **pow(lo,5)**), and it gets right.

Is there any solution ?

Comment: What is the content of k? what wrong number does it output?

Comment: Please indent your code before posting the question.

Comment: You scan `double`floating-point numbers with `%d`. You should use `%lf`. (Your compiler will warn you about such errors when you enable warnings.)

Comment: Your using the wrong format through out the whole of your program %d is for int not double

Comment: Adding to the answers: You need to find out how to turn on warnings for your compiler, and follow their advice. My compiler would have told me exactly what the answers below are saying, without having to ask anybody.

Comment: @gnasher729, to be fair, not _all_ compilers analyse that deeply. I was quietly impressed the first time I saw `gcc` do that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%d` is *not* the correct `scanf` format specifier for a double. You need to use `%lf` instead<sup>1</sup>.

If you were to print out the values for `k[]` after you'd read them in, you'd find they were rather different from what you expected.

For example, consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    double d1, d2;
    printf ("> ");
    scanf ("%lf %d", &d1, &d2); // one right, one wrong.
    printf ("Input was: %f %f\n", d1, d2);
    return 0;
}
```

Running that gives you:

```
pax$ ./testprog
> 3.14159 2.71828
Input was: 3.141590 -0.000000
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `C11 7.21.6.2 The fscanf function /10` says it best:

> If *[the object receiving the value]* does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `%lf` format specifier for `double` instead of `%d` which is for `int`